# Python, while parsing through a string, if character then new line

Tags: python

If i have a string as show below (simplified for example purposes)

```
myString = 

"Hello world, the weather is nice today} How are you today?"
```

Is there a way that I can parse through the string, and

```
if "}" then \n
```

so my end result would be,

```
"Hello world, the weather is nice today}
How are you today?"
```

Comment: `str.replace("}", "\n")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using `replace()` method:

```
myString = "Hello world, the weather is nice today} How are you today"

print(myString.replace('}', '}\n'))
```

Outputs:

```
Hello world, the weather is nice today}
 How are you today
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do `myString.replace("}","}\n")`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method as would be described by many is to `replace` `}` with `}\n`

But, in case you are feeling fancy, you can use [look-behind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) with regex ;-)

```
>>> re.sub('(?<=})','\n',s)
```

#driver values :

```
IN : s = "Hello world, the weather is nice today} How are you today?"
OUT : 'Hello world, the weather is nice today}\n How are you today?'
```